# What is the difference between the information stored in $v_hist_queries and $hist_plan_prolog_n of netezza system tables/views

Tags: sql, database, netezza

As per the netezza documents :

> [The $v_hist_queries view shows information about the completed queries and their status, runtime seconds (for total, cumulative queued, prep time and GRA time), and number of plans. The $v_hist_successful_queries and $v_hist_unsuccessful_queries views show the same information as $v_hist_queries, but filters that information depending on whether each query was successful.](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.adm.doc/r_sysadm_v_hist_queries.html)
>
> [The $hist_query_prolog_n table contains the initial data that is collected at the start of a query.](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.adm.doc/r_sysadm_hist_query_prolog_schema.html)

When I counted the number of queries in both the tables for a certain databases, the number of entries in $v_hist_queries were always greater than the number of entries in $hist_query_prolog_n.

Which are those extra rows in $v_hist_queries?

Shouldn't the number of rows be same in both the tables?

Answer (score 0):

`$v_hist_queries` has the query and query related information like query, start-time.

`$hist_plan_prolog_n` has the query schema and username i.e from which schema & user the query is fired in the Netezza database instance.